# Rails Controller show params[:text] from create action and back to new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When you have a `new` and `create` action with the purpose of a simple form that does a calculation (tableless). How do you show what was entered in the text boxes after the create action `redirect_to` the the `new` action, so the user sees their existing values.

The controller looks like this

```
   def new
      @sum = Sum.new
      @result = session[:result]
    end

  def create
    @sum = Sum.new(sum_params)
    if @sum.valid?
      result = Sum.calculate_total(@sum.first_number, @sum.second_number)
      session[:result] = result
      redirect_to new_sum_path
    else
      session[:result] = nil
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def sum_params
      params.require(:sum).permit(:first_number, :second_number)
    end
end
```

The view looks like this

```
<h1>Result = <%= result %></h1>

<%= form_for @sum do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :first_number %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_number, class: 'form-input', placeholder: '1' %>

  <%= f.label :second_number %>
  <%= f.text_field :second_number, class: 'form-input', placeholder: '2' %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The model has a method for the calcuation

```
def self.calculate_total(a,b)
  a + b
end
```

1. User enters numbers in 2 input text_fields (new action)
2. User hits submit (create action)
   Redirects back to `new` action with results showing using session[:result]
3. The input text_fields are blank. I would like this to show the
   numbers the was entered.

My questions:

- When validation kicks in.. the text fields have the user inputted values.. is this because it is contained within the same action and a redirect loses the information?
- To save the inputs when the user gets the results and redirects back to the `new` action I could store it in a session[:first_number] in the `new` and assign
  it if it's valid in the `create` action, is this okay or is there an easier/better way?

Comment: I was thinking, in my create action it redirects. Since all I'm doing will always show the new action. Would it be better to use a render action: 'new' and use instance variables to pass the results instead of relying on sessions?

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to `new_sum_path` it is forgetting the old sum.  If you want to display the old values, you could pass the current `@sum.id` through:

```
redirect_to new_sum_path(old_sum_id: @sum.id)
```

And then in your new action have:

```
if(params[:old_sum_id])
  @sum = Sum.find(params[:old_sum_id])
else
  @sum = Sum.new
end
```

This way, `form_for @sum` should pick up on those existing values and fill them in as defaults.

Comment: Thanks for thanking the time to respond. Would this work if I'm using a tableless model that doesn't store the record?